# Need to implement in another class

Tags: java, class, reference

I have this class:

```
public class ShoppingList {

    public int calculateTotal(){
        int sum = 0;
        for(Item item : items){
            sum += item.getPrice();
        }
        return sum;
    }

}
```

Now, I need to make something like this in another class:

```
if (calculateTotal > 25) {
      --some stuff--
}
```

How to reference this CalculateTotal correctly?

Comment: 1. Instantiate a `ShoppingList` object (or pass one in as argument) - 2. Call `calculateTotal` on it. - 3. Profit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Instantiate your class and use the method with the new object

```java
    ShoppingList myShoppingList = new ShopingList();
    if(myShopingList.calculateTotal() > 25){
        // some stuff
    }
```

2. Make your `calculateTotal` method static and use it without the need of the instance.

```java
    public class ShoppingList {
        public static int calculateTotal(){
            int sum = 0;
            for(Item item : items){
                sum += item.getPrice();
            }
            return sum;
        }
     }
```

And then

```
if(ShoppingList.calculateTotal() > 25){
    // some stuff
}
```